# there should be a diabetic tag for diabetic users!

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be [diabetic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diabetic)? I really believe there should be one!
[diabetic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diabetic) would allow questions featuring diabetes to be noted by users.

Comment: Let's figure out how to handle questions like this before we worry about tagging them: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/can-we-handle-questions-about-diabetic-friendly-food

Comment: how about a diabetic board then if there isn't one already?

Comment: If you're really serious about it, [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the place for proposing new sites. It does take a lot of work to get things off the ground and make sure there'll be enough support and people and questions for it to work out.

Comment: That said: [health.se] exists for many kinds of health questions, and we'll absolutely take well-defined cooking questions, it's just that we want "how do I reduce the sugar in X?" not "how do I make X diabetic-friendly?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't sound that useful to me. It doesn't indicate something well-defined about the question, which is pretty much the point of tags.

As rumtscho points out in [Can we handle questions about diabetic-friendly food?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/can-we-handle-questions-about-diabetic-friendly-food), questions about cooking for diabetics need to clearly specify goals (e.g. "low-carb"). If we want to tag those questions, we should probably do it based on those specific goals, not the vague "diabetic-friendly" notion.

Answer (score 2):

That would put answerers in the awkward position where their answers would be assumed qualified answers concerning suitability for diabetics - and unless I am mistaken, unlike a clear allergy *where its is black-and-white about avoiding a contaminant or else*, judging that really sounds like a health topic and/or like something that takes a health professional, trained diet cook, or otherwise specially knowledgeable and/or trained person to do.